# Issues with custom build NodeMCU Firmware, After flashing the custom build firmware to ESP-12E module giving the following error messages

Tags: nodemcu

Flashed NodeMCU_float_0.9.6-dev_20150704 on ESP-12E module gpio,timers,file,wifi, mqtt ,tcp and udp connections are working with no issues but i tried HTTP requests like HTTP GET and POST now this time it's giving error

> attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value))

HTTP GET request code

```
http.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

it's giving the error messages as

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (test.lua:1: attempt to
>   index global 'http' (a nil value))

I thought that the Firmware version i am using Flashed NodeMCU_float_0.9.6-dev_20150704 is not included HTTP module and built the custom build firmware with http,mqtt,net,node,wifi,timer,uart,file and gpio after flashing this custom build firmware contentiously sending the error message

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x40100000, len 29308, room 16 
tail 12
chksum 0x9c
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2228, room 12 
tail 8
chksum 0xe5
load 0x3ffe88b4, len 8, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0x86
csum 0x86
Fatal exception 0(IllegalInstructionCause):
epc1=0x40270858, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x4026d205, depc=0x00000000
```

with 748800 baud rate

Comment: I suggest you spend a minute or two to familiarize yourself with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I fixed all the formatting issues for now.

Comment: Also, mention which 'custom build' firmware you used, which version, did you build it yourself, did you use the cloud service, dev or master branch?

Comment: Thank you Marcel Stör.. I am using Custom build Firmware Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.1 .. .... Did the things you suggested now i can able to do simple http.post(),http.get()  with no issues ... But i need your support for how to send http.post() or http.get() with headers and body

Comment: and how to attach binary file in http body

Comment: @Anudeep good to know the flash issue is solved. Pls accept the answer so that StackOverflow can mark this as closed. And then let's continue on your [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38370435/131929).

Comment: working for HTTP Connections , But it's not working for HTTPS Connections.

Comment: That's again a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you also flash the `esp_init_data_default.bin` to its correct location.

Get [Espressif NON-OS SDK 1.5.1](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&p=5315) and extract `esp_init_data_default.bin`. Then flash it to address 0x7c000.

With esptool the command would be as follows:

```
esptool.py --port <USB-port-with-ESP8266> write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m 0x00000 <nodemcu-firmware>.bin 0x7c000 esp_init_data_default.bin
```

See http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/flash/#upgrading-from-sdk-09x-firmware for details.